# Quadro K4000 has double precision for CUDA?

Tags: cuda, precision, nvidia

Just bought a Quadro K4000 3GB card but it seems there is no double precision (DP) support in this card. Several reviews say the same.

Is there anyway to confirm if it does DP or not? My intended use is for CUDA programming for scientific number crunching, so DP is a must.

Comment: No matter where it seems from, you should look more carefully. [GPUs with compute capability 1.3 and higher support double precision floating point in hardware](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-faq). At the same time, [K4000 have compute capability 3.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus).

Comment: This question is off-topic and I have voted to close it.

Comment: @Drop, pardon my ignorance, but K4000 does not have any FP64 core, all are FP32 cores. So how can it support double precision??

Comment: @ShadowWarrior Where does this information comes from?

Comment: To be more specific: A Quadro K4000 has a total of 32 DP units. Quadro's are not made for scientific computing. (Most) Tesla's are.

Comment: @Shadow, could you please provide a reference for that info?

Comment: Using the same logic on that you can count to more than 10 using your hands fingers, a 32bit unit can do maths with higher bits. The difference is that it needs more instructions. So where a quadro can use a single instruction to add 2 32b numbers, it would need 3 or 4 to add 64b numbers (not really 3 or 4, but an approximation). If you were to have the a GPU in the Tesla family, then you'd be able to do these things faster, with less overheat

Answer (score 1):

As [Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1607442) already mentioned you can find a general info about DP arithmetic in the [CUDA FAQ](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-faq):

> *Q: Does CUDA support double precision arithmetic?*
>   Yes. GPUs with compute capability 1.3 and higher support double precision floating point in hardware.

And [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) you see all compute capabilities of CUDA-enabled products. There you will find that the compute capability of the Quadro K4000 is 3.0.

If you want to find how many DP units the card has you have may have a look at the [anandtech article](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6813/nvidia-launches-quadro-k4000-k2000-k2000d-k600) where you will find out that the ratio of DP units to cores is 1:24. As the K4000 has 768 cores it ensues that there are 32 DP units in total.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. If K4000 has DP cores, then why no DP GFLOPS published by Nvidia? And can I use a Fermi Quadro 4000 in tandem with Kepler K4000 where Fermi 4000 will be solely used as DP compute card??

Comment: @ShadowWarrior I am curios about that too. Of course it is not a info they want to use for marketing but imho they should provide that info somewhere. Regarding your second question: Right now I do not see a problem using both cards but I do not have much knowledge in that field. The question is if it is useful. What would you do with the K4000 then if you need DP only?

Comment: I'd use the K4000 for graphics only and the 4000 for CUDA compute only. Now question is how do I assign them both to these separate role?